# How to get the list of features which are actually used by XGBoost

Tags: xgboost, feature-selection

If the input data have 300 features, and if I setup the XGBoost with 3 trees and 3 level for depth of each tree, the 300 features cannot all be used for sure. But when I call `model.get_booster().feature_names`, all 300 features were returned.

My guess is that the `model.get_booster().feature_names` returns all the features in the training data, not the features used by the XGBoost model.

Is there a way to check which variables are actually used by the model? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by *features used by the classifier*? Thanks.

Comment: @edesz Sorry for the confusion. I meant to say XGBoost model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Booster.feature_names` attribute is the description of the training dataset - which features, in which order.

In principle, you could query feature importances as `model.feature_importances`. The thinking goes that "used" features have non-zero values, and "unused" features have zero values.

The correct approach would be to traverse XGBoost tree data structure, and collect node split indices (which correspond to column indices in your training dataset). If your model config is `n_estimators = 3` and `max_depth = 3` then, by definition, there can be at most `3 * 2^3` unique "used" features.

It's probably hard to implement such tree traversal in Python code, because the internal state of the `Booster` object is not exposed via public (Python facing-) APIs. But you could dump the `Booster` object in JSON data format and parse/traverse that.

For reference purposes, you could export your XGBoost model into a PMML document using the [JPMML-XGBoost](https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-xgboost) library (or its [SkLearn2PMML](https://github.com/jpmml/sklearn2pmml) package front-end), and open the resulting PMML XML file in a text editor. The conversion to the PMML representation only retains "used" features.